# Can't target downloaded Android build tools tools

Tags: android, cordova, windows-10

I've downloaded [Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#tos-header) (*Get just the command line tools* for Windows) and unpacked them to *C:\ProgramData\AndroidSdk*. Then I added *C:\ProgramData\AndroidSdk* and *C:\ProgramData\AndroidSdk\bin* to the *PATH* environmental variable. I also added *ANDROID_HOME* variable and set it to *C:\ProgramData\AndroidSdk*.

When I execute *cordova build android* I get the following error message.

> - Where:
>     Script 'C:\Source\Poc\CordovaApplication01\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle' line: 68
> - What went wrong:
>     A problem occurred evaluating project ':CordovaLib'.
>     No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.

By the error message I understand that the tools aren't found but I'm not sure what to do about it. When I remove the added parts of *PATH* I get other errors (the same goes for *ANDROID_HOME*) so I'm assuming that those are set correctly.

How can I do better diagnostic now? I'm new to Android platform so it might be something fairly simple that I'm missing.

(I've added the platform Android and tried to follow the steps of every guide I've found. Some mention a directory called *tools* and *Platform-tools* but those aren't present in the downloaded ZIP file and I've been told that the since the *angular* command is deprecated, the structure of the ZIP might have changed.)

Comment: maybe [this](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/) will help

Comment: @StefanGolubovićq Thanks for the hint. Regrettably, I've already seen that page. I want to resolve it **without** installing the Android Studio. Also, they mention three bullet points (1. Android platform SDK, 2. Android SDK build tools, 3. Android Support Repository) but they don't say How to do it. I've read the page on the link below but that's for Android Studio... Suggestions?

Comment: which android platform version did you add? try cordova platform add android@6.2.3.

Answer (score 0):

Check the installed version of SDK build tools

```
sdkmanager --list
```

My example found `build-tools;27.0.3`

Then replace `defaultBuildToolsVersion` value on `platforms\android\build.gradle` with installed SDK build tools version
In my example `defaultBuildToolsVersion=27.0.3`